# How to restart consumer and consume rejected messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, twisted, amqp

Using txamqp client with a specific scenario as below:

1. Declare an exchange called 'messaging' *(type=topic)*

> ```
> yield amqp.chan.exchange_declare(exchange='messaging', type='topic')
> ```

2. Setup a consumer

> ```
> yield amqp.named_queue_declare(queue="submit.sm_all")
> yield amqp.chan.queue_bind(queue="submit.sm_all", exchange="messaging", routing_key="submit.sm.*")
> yield amqp.chan.basic_consume(queue="submit.sm_all", no_ack=False, consumer_tag='qtag')
> ```

3. Publish **50 Messages**

> ```
>    for i in range(50):
>        yield amqp.publish(exchange='messaging', routing_key="submit.sm.connector01", 
>            content=Content(str(i)))
> ```

4. Start the consumer with a callback requeuing all consumed messages

> ```
> queue = yield amqp.client.queue('qtag')
> queue.get().addCallback(self._callback_reject_and_requeue_all).addErrback(self._errback)
> ```

5. Stop the consumer after **5 seconds**:

> ```
> yield queue.close()
> ```

At this stage, the queue is still full of 50 messages as they were all rejected and requeued (the callback were fired many times).

6. Start the consumer again:

> ```
> queue = yield amqp.client.queue('qtag')
> queue.get().addCallback(self._callback).addErrback(self._errback)
> ```

7. Stop the consumer after **5 seconds**:

> ```
> yield queue.close()
> ```

The problem is that the callback were never fired after starting the consumer in step 6, and the queue remains full of 50 messages.

**Note:**

- Messages are rejected like this:

> ```
> yield amqp.chan.basic_reject(delivery_tag=message.delivery_tag, requeue = 1)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to cleanly stop the consumer (step 5), basic_cancel must be used:

5. Stop the consumer after 5 seconds:

   yield amqp.chan.basic_cancel(consumer_tag = 'qtag')
6. Start the consumer again:

   yield amqp.chan.basic_consume(queue="submit.sm_all", no_ack=False, consumer_tag='qtag')
   queue = yield amqp.client.queue('qtag')
   queue.get().addCallback(self._callback).addErrback(self._errback)

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference whether message was rejected or not - it will reside on top of queue and can be picked by any consumer (or will be removed from queue if you use TTL or length-limiting and such limits will be reached).

You can't also consume only previously rejected messages while it can't be defined on server side. In fact you can only consume messages on by one from queue (they are strict FIFO queues).

As a workaround, you may set up [Dead Letter Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and reject messages with `requeue=false`, then they will be moved to your target queue, according to DLX routing flow. Then you can consume rejected messages from there, but in general, it is common to reject messages with requeue to the same queue they was consumed, unless special logic required.

And you can also re-publish messages you want to reject where you want, bit it even sounds a bit rusty.

**P.S.:**

Note, that when you call **`yield`** on function, it **doesn't run function body instead, it returns generator object**.

Comment: Do you mean that rejected messages will go to the current queue ? if it is the case then when i start my consumer again with the same queue why it doesnt see the rejected messages ?

Comment: I've added note about yield statement. What about using `return` instead of `yield`? It should help.

Comment: Nothing to do with yield, it is just blocking till i get response from a call, i use it to simplify the code and not to use callbacks (amqp object is a txamqp client using twisted framework, an event based one)